# How to filter objects based on given condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm new to this community and just started programming I couldn't find anything about this topic can anyone please solve this.
I need to filter names who's each points in array above 75.
i have tried this and unable iterate over an array.

```js
const candidatesList = [{'name':'Blake Hodges', 'points':[76,98,88,84]},{'name':'James Anderson', 'points':[0,98,12,13]}]

const arrayOfSelecetedCandidates=[]
  for(let object of candidatesList){
      if (candidatesList.every(candidatesList.points>75)){
         arrayOfSelecetedCandidates.push(candidatesList.name)
      }
  }
  console.log(arrayOfSelecetedCandidates);
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate manually with a `for` loop, just use `const filtered = candidatesList.filter( c => c.points.every( p => p > 75 ) );`

Comment: Your `candidates`'s array's objects don't have identical keys. Keys in JS are case-sensitive, but `Points`  and `points` are different. You need to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want this?

```js
const candidatesList = [{'name':'Blake Hodges', 'points':[76,98,88,84]},{'name':'James Anderson', 'points':[0,98,12,13]}]

const arrayOfSelecetedCandidates=[]
  for(let object of candidatesList){
      if (object.points.every(i=>i>75))
         arrayOfSelecetedCandidates.push(object.name)
  }
  console.log(arrayOfSelecetedCandidates);
```

But as @Dai pointed out filter is always better if you want to test an array and return item that pass the test:

```js
const candidatesList = [{'name':'Blake Hodges', 'points':[76,98,88,84]},{'name':'James Anderson', 'points':[0,98,12,13]}]

const arrayOfSelecetedCandidates=candidatesList.filter(i=>i.points.every(y=>y>75))
console.log(arrayOfSelecetedCandidates)
```

Comment: I'm curious why there's almost no whitespace in your code - don't you find it hard to read? How do you eyeball-match nested parentheses?

Comment: @Dai, is it really hard for people to read it??? Never realize that before. I sometimes feel that it is pretty cool to shorten the code as much as possible. (I could fix it if needed) Do you mind kindly share some your  experiences/suggestions? (Just a beginner) =)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [Array.every()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const candidatesList = [{
    'name': 'Blake Hodges',
    'points': [76, 98, 88, 84]
}, {
    'name': 'James Anderson',
    'points': [0, 98, 12, 13]
}];

let res = candidatesList.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.points.every((item) => item > 75)
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: How is it different between the above answer

Comment: @Shawn Thank you! Sorry, I missed that answer while writing my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I need to filter names who's each points in array above 75"*

Looking at the content of OP, I believe that's incorrect. It would make more sense if the desired output would be only the objects (aka candidates) that have an ***average of points*** at or above 75 not a total of 75 (although not explained very well). So the plan of attack would be:

- Get each of the candidates with a `for...of` loop:

  ```
  for (const candidate of candidates) {...
  ```
- Get each of the candidate's points (`candidate.points`) and get their sums using `.reduce()` (note: the return goes to a new property called `.total`). Then take that total and divide by the number of grades found in points array (it's `candidate.points.length` = 4):

  ```
  candidate.total = candidate.points.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur, 0);
  candidate.gpa = Math.floor(candidate.total / candidate.points.length);
  ```
- Once `candidate.gpa` is established, `.filter()` will determine if it is equal to or greater than 75.

  ```
  return candidates.filter(candidate => candidate.gpa >= 75);
  ```

```js
const candidates = [{
  'name': 'Blake Hodges',
  'points': [76, 98, 88, 84]
}, {
  'name': 'James Anderson',
  'points': [0, 98, 12, 13]
}, {
  'name': 'Zer0 0ne',
  'points': [100, 88, 91, 84]
}, {
  'name': 'Ronald McDonald',
  'points': [72, 51, 8, 89]
}];

const selected = candidates => {
  for (const candidate of candidates) {
    candidate.total = candidate.points.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur, 0);
    candidate.gpa = Math.floor(candidate.total / candidate.points.length);
  }
  return candidates.filter(candidate => candidate.gpa >= 75);
};

console.log(selected(candidates));
```